# QML changing size of image

Tags: image, qt, qml

I have an image object in QML (QtQuick 1.0), its height must be relative (in case of window scaling), but the problem is when I try to display this image in fullsize. Please look at the following part of my code:

```
 Image {
      id: selectionDialogImage
      source: "qrc:/Images/myImage.png"
      property int oldHeight: sourceSize.height
      sourceSize.height: testsList.height/3
      scale: 1
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
      anchors.left: parent.left
      visible: false
      property bool imageFullsize: false
      MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:
                  {
                    if(parent.imageFullsize)
                    {
                       parent.parent = selectionDialogQuestionText;
                       parent.sourceSize.width = undefined;
                       parent.sourceSize.height = testsList.height/3;
                       parent.anchors.horizontalCenter = undefined;
                       parent.anchors.verticalCenter = undefined;
                       parent.anchors.left = selectionDialogQuestionText.left;
                       parent.anchors.bottom = selectionDialogQuestionText.bottom;
                       parent.imageFullsize = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       parent.parent = mainItem;
                       parent.sourceSize.height = parent.oldHeight;
                       //parent.sourceSize.height = undefined;
                       parent.sourceSize.width = mainItem.width;
                       parent.anchors.horizontalCenter = mainItem.horizontalCenter;
                       parent.imageFullsize = true;
                    }
                  }
              }
       }
```

selectionDialogQuestionText is a default parent of my image item. mainItem is the largest item, it has size of the whole window. So I want to have the image size set on the basis of width when I'm displaying it on a fullscreen, but in another state I want to scale the image setting its height.

When I set `parent.sourceSize.width = mainItem.width;`, image isn't scaled, but its height is as previous (very little) so its proportions are inappropriate.

Can I store old height of source image in any way? I need something like const, because `property int oldHeight: sourceSize.heigh` is relative. Or is there a way to restore default size of image and then set height/width?

UPDATE #1:
I tried to use method described by @Mitch:

```
property int oldHeight
Component.onCompleted: {
   oldHeight = sourceSize.height
   }
   sourceSize.height: 250
```

but `console.log("oldHeight="+parent.oldHeight)` a few lines below shows `oldHeight=250`, not original height.

Comment: Can you provide illustrations of what you're trying to do? Your question is quite difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I store old height of source image in any way?

You can use `Component.onCompleted`:

```
Image {
    // ...
    Component.onCompleted: {
        oldHeight = sourceSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set `sourceSize.height: 250`, then it will always be 250, because that is evaluated before `Component.onCompleted` is run. You should set `sourceSize.height = 250` at the end of `Component.onCompleted` instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understood it some time ago, but it didn't resolve my problem beacuse original value of `sourceSize.height` was... strange. Finally, instead of resizing my image, I created another Rectangle (containing Image{}) as a child of mainItem (root element). So in `onClicked` I have only `imageFullscreenBox.imgSource = parent.source;` and `imageFullscreenBox.visible = true;`